# Group Pandas dataframe data in time intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I created a Pandas dataframe using Python, it looks like this:

```
Rate        Qty          Datetime
130  154.270343  2020-07-05 22:10
131  267.875561  2020-07-05 22:14
132  192.785490  2020-07-05 22:15
130  192.542386  2020-07-05 22:16
150  292.374318  2020-07-05 22:17
123  170.838072  2020-07-05 22:18
144  175.755412  2020-07-05 22:29
200  181.779834  2020-07-05 22:30
201  206.707950  2020-07-05 22:31
178  154.240175  2020-07-05 22:33
191  268.368463  2020-07-05 22:40
191  192.785490  2020-07-05 22:41
201  192.542386  2020-07-05 22:43
201  292.365318  2020-07-05 22:45
300  170.838072  2020-07-05 22:50
```

I need to change the date of every record, so that the new date needs to be the next "interval". An interval can be 30 minutes or 1 hour. If it's 30 minutes, `2020-07-05 22:10` becomes `2020-07-05 22:30`.

So here is the expected output:

```
Rate        Qty          Datetime
130  154.270343  2020-07-05 22:30
131  267.875561  2020-07-05 22:30
132  192.785490  2020-07-05 22:30
130  192.542386  2020-07-05 22:30
150  292.374318  2020-07-05 22:30
123  170.838072  2020-07-05 22:30
144  175.755412  2020-07-05 22:30
200  181.779834  2020-07-05 22:30
201  206.707950  2020-07-05 23:00
178  154.240175  2020-07-05 23:00
191  268.368463  2020-07-05 23:00
191  192.785490  2020-07-05 23:00
201  192.542386  2020-07-05 23:00
201  292.365318  2020-07-05 23:00
300  170.838072  2020-07-05 23:00
```

How can i achieve this? Do i have to loop through the dataframe or is there an operator that makes it easier to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for flooring timestamp and add 30 minutes if not already `Datetime` column is same like floored values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
d = df['Datetime'].dt.floor('30T')

df['Datetime'] = d.where(df['Datetime'].eq(d), d + pd.Timedelta('30Min'))
print (df)
    Rate         Qty            Datetime
0    130  154.270343 2020-07-05 22:30:00
1    131  267.875561 2020-07-05 22:30:00
2    132  192.785490 2020-07-05 22:30:00
3    130  192.542386 2020-07-05 22:30:00
4    150  292.374318 2020-07-05 22:30:00
5    123  170.838072 2020-07-05 22:30:00
6    144  175.755412 2020-07-05 22:30:00
7    200  181.779834 2020-07-05 22:30:00
8    201  206.707950 2020-07-05 23:00:00
9    178  154.240175 2020-07-05 23:00:00
10   191  268.368463 2020-07-05 23:00:00
11   191  192.785490 2020-07-05 23:00:00
12   201  192.542386 2020-07-05 23:00:00
13   201  292.365318 2020-07-05 23:00:00
14   300  170.838072 2020-07-05 23:00:00
```